# Laravel 9 routes not working with custom method

Tags: php, laravel

I have a large route file. All of my routes are working except for shop.calendar(returns 404). I'm truly baffled!

Here is my route file

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\LeadController;
use App\Http\Controllers\NoteController;
use App\Http\Controllers\ClientController;
use App\Http\Controllers\DeviceController;
use App\Http\Controllers\IntakeController;
use App\Http\Controllers\PaymentController;
use App\Http\Controllers\VehicleController;
use App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController;
use App\Http\Controllers\AppointmentController;
use App\Http\Controllers\ShopController;

Route::redirect('/', 'login');

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {

  Route::get('/dashboard', DashboardController::class)->name('dashboard');

  Route::controller(ShopController::class)->prefix('/shop')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', 'index')->name('shop.index');
    Route::get('/{id}', 'show')->name('shop.show');
    Route::get('/calendar', 'calendar')->name('shop.calendar');
  });

  Route::controller(LeadController::class)->prefix('/lead')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/create', 'create')->name('lead.create');
    Route::get('/{lead_view}', 'index')->name('lead.index');
    Route::get('/{id}', 'show')->name('lead.show');
    Route::post('/', 'store')->name('lead.store');
    Route::get('/edit/{id}', 'edit')->name('lead.edit');
    Route::patch('/{id}', 'update')->name('lead.update');
    Route::post('/{id}', 'follow')->name('lead.follow');
    Route::delete('/{id}', 'destroy')->name('lead.destroy');
  });

  Route::controller(ClientController::class)->prefix('/client')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/create', 'create')->name('client.create');
    Route::get('/{client_view}', 'index')->name('client.index');
    Route::get('/{id}', 'show')->name('client.show');
    Route::post('/', 'store')->name('client.store');
    Route::get('/edit/{id}', 'edit')->name('client.edit');
    Route::patch('/{id}', 'update')->name('client.update');
    Route::delete('/{id}', 'destroy')->name('client.delete');
  });

  Route::controller(IntakeController::class)->prefix('/intake')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/edit/{id}', 'edit')->name('intake.edit');
    Route::post('/', 'store')->name('intake.store');
  });

  Route::controller(VehicleController::class)->prefix('/vehicle')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/show/{id}', 'show')->name('vehicle.show');
    Route::post('/{id}', 'store')->name('vehicle.store');
  });

  Route::controller(NoteController::class)->prefix('/note')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/show/{id}', 'show')->name('note.show');
    Route::post('/', 'store')->name('note.store');
    Route::post('/storeLead', 'storeLead')->name('note.storeLead');
    Route::post('/storeClient', 'storeClient')->name('note.storeClient');
  });

  Route::controller(DeviceController::class)->prefix('/device')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/show/{id}', 'show')->name('device.show');
    Route::post('/{id}', 'store')->name('device.store');
  });

  Route::controller(AppointmentController::class)->prefix('/appointment')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/show/{id}', 'show')->name('appointment.show');
    Route::post('/{id}', 'store')->name('appointment.store');
  });

  Route::controller(PaymentController::class)->prefix('/payment')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/show/{id}', 'show')->name('payment.show');
    Route::post('/{id}', 'store')->name('payment.store');
  });


});


require __DIR__ . '/auth.php';
```

And here is the Shop Controller

```
class ShopController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $clients = Client::with(['vehicle', 'appointment'])
        ->where('default_location', 'home')->get(); 
        
        return view('shop.index',)->with(['clients' => $clients]);
    }

    public function calendar()
    {
        return "Testing...";

        // $clients = Client::with(['vehicle', 'appointment'])
        // ->where('default_location', 'home')->get();

        // return view('shop.calendar',)->with(['clients' => $clients]);
    }
```

Any reason this method would return a 404 ??? I have verified the route is working with route:list and cleared all cache. I've also tried renaming the method over a dozen times.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @OMi Shah's answer might be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because of the `Route::get('/{id}', 'show')->name('shop.show');` route. The request is getting handled/intercepted by this route. The `calender` path parameter is passed to the this route and causing the issue.

Switch the routes and it should fix the issue. Place the `shop.calender` named route before the `shop.show`.

**change:**

```
Route::controller(ShopController::class)->prefix('/shop')->group(function () {
    ...
    Route::get('/{id}', 'show')->name('shop.show');
    Route::get('/calendar', 'calendar')->name('shop.calendar');
});
```

**to:**

```
Route::controller(ShopController::class)->prefix('/shop')->group(function () {
    ...
    Route::get('/calendar', 'calendar')->name('shop.calendar');
    Route::get('/{id}', 'show')->name('shop.show');
});
```

**P.s:** *Also, if you could share your `show` method code, we can suggest you an answer without the need of switching the routes, via the type hinting.*

Comment: That fixed it instantly. Thank you so much for that. Is it considered good practice to always have the edit method last in the routes?

Comment: @theothernick, no but when you don't type hint route parameters then you need to place the routes that accepts parameters so that they don't intercept static route paths.